# Removing an outer element

Tags: jquery

I know that .wrap() will wrap elements in an outer element.  .wrap('h1') ,for example, would put  tags around the members of the selected set.  But is there a way to *remove*  outer elements.  Suppose, for example,  I want to remove the `<h1>`  tags added by the line above.

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: you can use unwrap() function to remove outer tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery `.unwrap()`:

> The `.unwrap()` method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the `.wrap()` method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/